# snakemake --profile PROFILE_NAME --dry-run results in "No config.yaml found", despite profile being located under .config/snakemake

Tags: slurm, snakemake, hpc

I recently created a Snakemake profile using the guide at [Snakemake-Profiles/slurm](https://github.com/Snakemake-Profiles/slurm). I was able to get the profile installed successfully, and it does work when calling the path directly. However, when using the profile name, such as

```bash
snakemake --profile slurm --dry-run
```

I get the error:

```bash
Error: profile given but no config.yaml found. Profile has to be given as 
either absolute path, relative path or name of a directory available in either 
/etc/xdg/snakemake or /home/GROUP/USERNAME/.config/snakemake.
```

I have indeed installed the profile under `~/.config/snakemake`. Here is the tree of this directory:

```
/home/GROUP/USERNAME/.config/snakemake
.
└── slurm
    ├── cluster_config.yaml
    ├── config.yaml
    ├── CookieCutter.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── CookieCutter.cpython-39.pyc
    │   └── slurm_utils.cpython-39.pyc
    ├── settings.json
    ├── slurm-jobscript.sh
    ├── slurm-status.py
    ├── slurm-submit.py
    └── slurm_utils.py

2 directories, 10 files
```

I can continue to specify the path to this profile when running Snakemake, but it would be useful to simply give it the name of the profile. Does anyone happen to know why Snakemake doesn't seem to be picking up that the profile `slurm` exists?

Comment: I have this issue too, but it's not consistent

Comment: Turns out I had a directory with the name of my profile in my workflow directory. Renaming it solved things.

Comment: @BFH I think that observation merits an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my issue by installing Snakemake in a Conda environment, and re-installing the profile. I'm not sure if it was the Conda environment or the profile re-install that fixed my issue.